# How do I sanitize meta box contents to prevent XSS attacks?

Tags: wordpress, security, xss, sanitization, meta-boxes

I know how to sanitize metabox content like

```
<img src=x onerror=console.log(hey) />
```

But how about the following?

```
<img src=x onerror=console.log(hey)<img src="x" />
```

Tried the code below, but doesn't seem to work.

```
wp_kses_post()
```

Tried using [balanceTags()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/balancetags/), striplashes(), [wp_kses_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/), etc.

[sanitize_text_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) would work obviously but it'd filter out all the HTML.

Comment: You need to pass your HTML string to `wp_kses_post()` for it to do something, eg. `$content = wp_kses_post( $content );`

Comment: If I pass the first example in `wp_kses_post()`, it will remove the JS, but if I pass the second example, it will remain. And that can be used for XSS.

Comment: Just tried it and the output of `wp_kses_post('<p>hello</p><img src=x onerror=console.log(hey)<img src="x" />')` was `<p>hello</p>&lt;img src=x onerror=console.log(hey)<img src="x" />`. Looks like it's working to me, no JS was executed on my browser (although the code is still malformed).

Comment: is `onerror` being passed from the user?

Answer (score 0):

if storing to the database you should use sanitze functions. if your outputting to the browser you should use escape functions.

```
<img src=<?php echo esc_url('x'); ?> onerror=<?php echo esc_attr('console.log(hey)'); ?><img src="<?php echo esc_url('x'); ?>" />
```

using [`wp_kses`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/)

```
$string = '<img src=x onerror=console.log(hey)<img src="x" />';

<?php echo wp_kses( $string, array( 'img' => array('src' => array() ), 'p' => array() ) ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo wp_kses( $string, 'data' ); ?>
```

Comment: From Patrick's comments sounds like it's user generated content. If so then Patrick doesn't have control over the HTML code (otherwise your suggestion would work), OP just wants to make sure that said HTML code is safe to use and won't introduce XSS vulnerabilities.